# Makefile with 2 files

Tags: c, linux, makefile

Hello!

I want to make Makefile.win which will make a tar.gz with 2 other  files(dodaj.c and another Makefile, both are in the same directory where i want use commend make ).My problem is

```
make dodaj.tar.gz
make: *** No rule to make target 'dodaj.tar.gz'.  Stop
```

Here is my code:

```
dodaj.tar.gz: dodaj.c Makefile
    mkdir dodaj-434686
    cp ./dodaj.c ./dodaj-434686
    cp ./Makefile ./dodaj-434686
    tar -czvf dodaj.tar.gz ./dodaj-43468
    rm -rf ./dodaj-434686
```

Comment: Using `./` just makes the code more unreadable. By default if you don't specify a path, then current directory is assumed.

Comment: i didn't  knew that, thanks.

Comment: I guess that your version of make uses make file `Makefile` by default, not `Makefile.win`. So, it could be that you are using the wrong make file. Try `make -f Makefile.win dodaj.tar.gz` to tell make that the make file to use is `Makefile.win`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make will look for files named 'makefile' and 'Makefile'.  If you are using Gnu make, it will also look for 'GNUmakefile'.  It does not look for 'Makefile.win'.  To use that file, you must do `make -f Makefile.win dodaj.tar.gz`